# How to calculate the smallest number possible based on digits (0-9) not used in a user inputted integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a code that will accept an integer input and then calculate the smallest number possible using digits not found in the inputted integer. The possible digits would be 0-9, however, 0 can not be the leading value in the output.

For example, if the user enters:

> 6789

the the program would output:

> 102345

How can I solve this?

Comment: The shown code uses functions unknown to me. Please provide a [mre] of that. Since also none of the shown code seems to be related to your goal please also provide a [mre] of your best own programming attempt and explain how it fails.

Comment: With your shown code, which is properly working for at least the input part, what happens if I provide input `0123`? And what would be the expected result for that input? I ask because the leading 0 is forbidden in output, but not in input. How did you test those code parts which you comment as properly working? Are you sure that the input has to be read as integer? I doubt that.

Comment: Have a look at things like std::string and std::min. You will find that std::string can report its own size. (std::string has an internal array that you can get access to and loop over).

Comment: Seems like you'd want to sort the digits you need to use and if the first one is a 0 swap it with the next one.

Comment: `012345` would be smaler, especially as octal. :)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow *however, 0 can not be the leading value in the output*

Comment: @AdrianMole I think your missed the :)

Answer (score 0):

The lowest number possible from any set of digits (ignoring, for now, the issue of the zero) comprises those digits in order; thus, from the digits `2`, `1`, `6` and `3`, the lowest number is `1236`.

So, we can start of with a list of all digits, in order, then run through the digits in the given input number (after we have converted that to a string), removing each of those digits from our list (if it's still in it). If we end up with a list whose first element is zero, we simply swap that with the second digit.

Here's a possible implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string numbs = "0123456789";
    int input;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::string check = std::to_string(input); // Convert our input to a string
    for (auto digit : check) { // Remove each digit in that from our list...
        size_t p;
        if ((p = numbs.find(digit)) != std::string::npos) numbs.erase(p, 1);
    }
    // A basic error check that at least one digit remains ...
    if (numbs.length() == 0) {
        std::cout << "No digit left with which to make a number!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // Swap first two digits if first is zero and there is at least one other ...
    if (numbs[0] == '0' && numbs.length() > 1) std::swap(numbs[0], numbs[1]);
    int answer = std::stoi(numbs);
    std::cout << answer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I have used the `std::string` container class from the Standard Library; in many ways, that acts like an array of characters; however, if you want to use *actual* arrays, you could readily adapt the shown code to use them.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The goal/task is to calculate a *number*. That's why I added the conversion to an `int`. The subsequent `cout` operation is added just to demonstrate the program's success.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow A fair point ... edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation. Same algorithm as from Adrian . . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    // Basic string
    std::string allDigits{ "0123456789" };

    // Get input. Digits only
    if (std::string input{}; std::getline(std::cin, input) and std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isdigit)) {

        // Erase from the allDigits string the characters that are in the input string
        std::erase_if(allDigits, [&](const char d) { return std::any_of(input.begin(), input.end(), [d](const char c) { return c == d; }); });

        // Take care of leading 0
        if ((allDigits.length() > 1) and allDigits.front() == '0') std::swap(allDigits[0], allDigits[1]);

        // Show result
        std::cout << allDigits << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```